# Are there any funding issues going on in the US universities which are affecting PhD admissions this year?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states, computer-science

Location: USA 
Department: Computer Science

I’ve applied to 8 schools for PhD admissions this year and have only received a rejection from one so far (a private university). Rest of my applications are to public universities in the USA. I understand it is mostly a rejection if they’ve already started sending out offers to other candidates. But that is not the case this year. Speaking with the admissions committee and checking self-reporting websites like gradcafe, I see no offers have been rolled out at this point in time (previous years admissions have finished rolling out by end of Feburary). Is there any specific issue going on in universities and will that affect the acceptance rates?

Comment: I don't know about CS but the programs I know about are at their normal pace. You'll find out when you find out, but definitely do some contingency planning (which should be done from the start).

Comment: @BryanKrause: constructive, measured guidance. +1